# Not able to send ether to a contract contract using Ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, testing

I am testing a contract in Hardhat. I need to fund the contract with some fake ethers first in `before` hook but I am getting `Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit` error even everything looks good.

Code:

```
 [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
    // Deploying ERC20 token
    const BallonsToken = await ethers.getContractFactory("Ballons");
    erc20Token = await BallonsToken.deploy();
  
    // Deploying Uniswap Clone Contract
    const UniswapClone = await ethers.getContractFactory("UniswapClone");
    uniswapClone = await UniswapClone.deploy(erc20Token.address);

    // funding uniswap contract
    console.log("contract: ",uniswapClone.address)
    await owner.sendTransaction({
      to: uniswapClone.address,
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")
    })
```

May anyone knows what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: does UniswapClone accept ether?

Comment: @MajdTL what do you mean by does it accept?

Comment: Does it has a received function in the `UniswapClone`?

Comment: Contracts could have functions to revert accepting ether check this article: https://blockchain-academy.hs-mittweida.de/courses/solidity-coding-beginners-to-intermediate/lessons/solidity-2-sending-ether-receiving-ether-emitting-events/topic/fallback-function-and-receive-ether-function/